# Load UIImage from documents directory

Tags: ios

I'm trying to load a `UIImage` from the documents directory and set it to a `UIImageView` as per below:

```
NSString  *pngfile = [[MyUtil getLocalDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"school.png"];
NSLog(@"%@", pngfile);
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pngfile]) {
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pngfile];            
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    [schoolImage setImage:img];
}
```

However, whenever I try the above, the image never loads. The image is in `Documents/MyAppCustomDirectory/school.png`. Is the above correct to load from that directory?

I also tried a few others: `UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile`, among other ways based on SO responses.

Comment: Show the code for `MyUtil getLocalDirectory`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get the documents directory you should use:

```
NSArray  *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir  = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString  *pngfile = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"school.png"];
```

I'm not quite sure if you also need to append the 'MyAppCustomDirectory', but I don't think so.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4 Solution:**

```
guard let documentsDirectory = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                                                in: .userDomainMask,
                                                                appropriateFor:nil,
                                                                create:false)
                else {
                    // May never happen
                    print ("No Document directory Error")
                    return nil
                }

// Construct your Path from device Documents Directory
var imagesDirectory = documentsDirectory

// Only if your images are un a subdirectory named 'images'
imagesDirectory.appendPathComponent("images", isDirectory: true)

// Add your file name to path
imagesDirectory.appendPathComponent("school.png")

// Create your UIImage?    
let result = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagesDirectory.path)
```